# Theano warning: The same cache key is associated to different modules

Tags: python, github, neural-network, theano

I've been using Lasagne for a while to run Neural Networks. I had installed it by downloading the repo from github and then doing `python setup.py install`.
Today I tried to updating to the latest version. This is what I've done:

-rename the previous lasagne folder to lasagne_old.

-create a new lasagne folder with the new repo

-`python setup.py install`

The install completed fine.
However as soon as I try running the usual Neural Networks it starts giving errors:

```
from lasagne import nonlinearities
from lasagne import layers
from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 750 Ti
from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
WARNING (theano.gof.cmodule): The same cache key is 
associated to different modules (/home/g/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.11.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid-x86_64-2.7.9-64/tmpRIO67Y/c07737f1d301ae23e9d459b32aa6f2b5.so and 
/home/g/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.11.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-debian-
wheezy-sid-x86_64-2.7.9-64/tmpwUH2fJ/57987abfa26302054d6be91525f69179.so).
 This is not supposed to happen! You may need to manually delete your cache directory to fix this.
```

How could I fix this? And, moving forward, what is the right way to update  a package from a repo?

Answer (score 4):

Use the command [`theano-cache clear`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#updating-theano). I had a similar problem and it solved it. Hope it's helpful

> If you installed NumPy/SciPy with yum/apt-get, updating NumPy/SciPy with pip/easy_install is not always a good idea. This can make Theano crash due to problems with BLAS (but see below). The versions of NumPy/SciPy in the distribution are sometimes linked against faster versions of BLAS. Installing NumPy/SciPy with yum/apt-get/pip/easy_install won’t install the development package needed to recompile it with the fast version. This mean that if you don’t install the development packages manually, when you recompile the updated NumPy/SciPy, it will compile with the slower version. This results in a slower Theano as well. To fix the crash, you can clear the Theano cache like this:

```
theano-cache clear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ theano-cache clear
```

and optionally

```
$ theano-cache purge
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: Yeah, `clear` might not completely remove cache and then there would be warning. `purge` will clean up all of them. Depending on dependency such as compiler installation there could be some problem. I'd re-install theano then.